# How to check Rabbit MQ nodes running status using C# application

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am trying to build an application which will check and monitor the Rabbit MQ nodes running status using C# .Net technology. After finding some references on the internet I started working on it but getting some issues.

Rabbit MQ url: http://rabbitmq-vip.testlocal.com:15672/#/

userId: rmq-admin

password: dev12rabbit

host: 10.2.39.21

I am using the below code to access the url

```cs
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
string ur = "amqp://rmq-admin:dev12rabbit@rabbitmq-vip.testlocal.com:15672/#/";
Uri myUri = new Uri(ur, UriKind.Absolute);
factory.Uri = myUri;
IConnection conn = null;
try
{
    conn = factory.CreateConnection();
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
                
}
```

I am getting the exception as "None of the specified endpoints were reachable". But this url is working on the browser.

Also I am trying to check the status of node: rabbit@GASDSRMQ01 as shown below in the image. What could be wrong here

[image]

Comment: seems like the url is only accessible on http

Comment: yes, its an internal url

Answer (score 0):

Ehsan's comment gives you the key to the problem. The RabbitMQ web manager uses the http protocol, not amqp.  Thus, you should change this line

```
string ur = "amqp://rmq-admin:dev12rabbit@rabbitmq-vip.testlocal.com:15672/#/";
```

To this

```
string ur = "http://rmq-admin:dev12rabbit@rabbitmq-vip.testlocal.com:15672/#/";
```